# How to automatically wait until a function is done with promises in node.js/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a module that when instantiate it, it runs a lot of asynchronous functions.

```
var freader = new filesreader();    // <-- this runs a lot of async functions
var IMG_ARRAY = freader.get_IMG_ARRAY();   // <-- I get the array that stuff gets put into
console.log(IMG_ARRAY); // <-- this prints an empty array
```

When I create a new `filesreader` it, creates `[]` and then runs a lot of async code to put stuff in the array. Then I want to get the array and print it. But since theres async code, if I try to get the array in the next line and print it, it will be empty. I need to wait until all the async code has finished in the module, but theres so much stuff I don't want to manually track everything and put callbacks everywhere. Is there a way I canjust automatically wait until the function has finished fully through some hack?

Thanks

Comment: Normally an async function will provide a callback, return a `Promise`, or will be an `EventEmitter`. Either it will do those things (or similar) or you will have no way of knowing when it has finished. What is the module?

Comment: It's my own module with stuff about reading files asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing `filesreader` so it returns an array that will be populated, have it return a Promise:

```
function get_IMG_ARRAY() {
  var result = [];
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // All your async stuff, then eventually...
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

That way, all you have to do to consume it is this:

```
var freader = new filesreader();
freader.get_IMG_ARRAY().then(function (IMG_ARRAY) {
  console.log(IMG_ARRAY);
}, function (err) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

Comment: But In the module I am calling several other async functions at same time without chaining them. Don't i have to call resolve after they all finish?

Comment: You'll have to chain them so you can wait before calling resolve. Or use `async.parallel` or `Promise.all` to wait for things in parallel.

Comment: What if I don't want to chain them, is there another way?

Comment: You somehow need callbacks; that's the fundamental JS way.